# Trying to generate type typescript after installing Supabase CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, supabase, remix

I ran supabase `npx gen types typescript --project-id 'PROJECTID' > db_types.ts` which I got an error

```
cp: cannot stat '/c/Users/PC/Desktop/chatter/node_modules/.bin/template.gen': No such file or directory
```

I try this and it worked

```
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id 'PROJECTID' > db_types.ts
```